# How to remove depth of a span border in Bootstrap/css?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As you can see on this image there is a top border (with a depth effect), that I need to remove (I just want to have the text written on the orange background, with no effect):

[image]

Here is the code:

```
  <div class="form-group col-lg-3">
    <div>
      <label for="message"><br></label>
      <div>
        <span class="form-control hide" id="error-msg" style="color: red; background-color:#ED7D31;">different passwords</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I tried to add `"border: none"` or `"border: 0px"` in the span style attribute, but nothing change. Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: do you need a `border-top` with no extra depth, or you don't want the `border-top` at all ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't the border. There is a box-shadow at the top of the span.
Below the code to remove it

```
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-moz-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
```